# Have an unclear homework assignment for Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, events

The assignment states

> "Write a program to print only even numbers between 6 and 16 using
>   events."

while in the class we only use CL applications just having a button wouldnt work. So I thought about using an if than statement that would raise an event if CurrentNumber is even with mod 2 as current number is declared as 6

```
        While CurrentNumber < 17
        If CurrentNumber Mod 2 Then
            RaiseEvent Even()
            CurrentNumber = CurrentNumber + 1
        Else
            CurrentNumber = CurrentNumber + 1
        End If
    End While
```

But how would I handle the event to console.writeline(CurrentNumber) basically what I need to do is to make a program that prints even numbers using events how I was trying to solve the problems was to invoke in event if the number is even that shows the current number

Comment: I am sorry, but could you explain more clearly what you need to do? Especially with your last sentence, it makes no sense.

Comment: give yourself a real handle, and know that it is an if "then" statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. What if you were to build a class that only had one purpose--to count numbers and raise events when an even or odd number occurs? Let's say this class is called `Counter`.

Next, what if your `Program` class had an instance of the `Counter` class and had an event handler only for the `Even` event? The handler could perform a `Console.WriteLine()` each time an even number occurs.

Comment: Thanks; chose this solution as the actual solution because it it helped me understand the material more compared to just completing the assignment!

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, you are doing unnessecary work with the "mod 2" bit.
Just limit your for loop to the range you would like:

```
For Index As Int32 = 6 To 16 Step 2
  RaiseEvent EvenNumber(Index)
Next
```

Then your EvenNumber event setup would look similar to:

```
Public Event EvenNumber(number)

'  In program startup:
AddHandler Me.EvenNumber, AddressOf EvenNumberHandler

' later...
Private Sub EvenNumberHandler(ByVal number As Int32)
  Console.WriteLine(number)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice job of doing the work instead of instructing. Sort of defeated the whole purpose of giving the assignment, didn't you? You just taught how to copy and paste - nice.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that having an `OddNumber` event is "unnecessary work". It makes sense to have events that cover both possibilities. The class is more "general purpose" that way, rather than being very specialized as in your example.

Comment: @danm id agree, but in this case the op made no mention of using odd numbers either in the description nor in the example code, yet specifically mentions an even event.